# SQLAlchemy: Why would you not use a scoped session?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to understand use of [sessions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session.html) in SQLAlchemy.
One thing I'm struggling with - the [scoped_session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/contextual.html) seems to be foolproof - you ask for a session, you get back the same thread-local version every time, you close it off when you're done with it. The docs [clearly state](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-thread-safe) that this is the way to go for concurrent usage, but it seems to me that it should also avoid other, simpler bugs like mistakenly opening a new session when a parent function has already created one, for example.

I guess the only reason **not** to use the `scoped_session` is if you need multiple separate sessions, e.g. if you're accessing two databases at the same time - is that about right? Why else might you stick to use of regular `Session` objects?

Answer (score 1):

The only drawback to scope_session is that it uses a thread local and whether this is a drawback is also up for debate.

Understand that a thread local is essentially a global variable which is being passed around all through out your code for increased clarity. You need to make sure you don't abuse it by inadvertently passing it to a different thread or accidentally storing it somewhere for later use.

For more information [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage)

Comment: Thanks, but I (roughly) understand what thread-local means. I get that you wouldn't want to try to pass a thread-local object between threads, and you don't need to store it, because it's effectively a singleton in the context of that thread. I'm looking for practical failure-cases or situations where a regular session is more useful than a (thread-local) scoped_session.

Comment: So the only place I can think of is when doing concurrency - but then its not really an advantage so much as a must. If you have multiple threads you will have to create session objects manually and pass them *or* you could allow all the threads to use the same session, useful if you want them all to have the same read only view of the data

Comment: I agree that for concurrency, you use scoped_session, cf http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-thread-safe - I'm aware of the benefits, but looking for drawbacks - I'll perhaps edit the question a bit to try and be clearer.